# Parsing argument which is a comma separated string, passed to a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that takes one argument which is a comma separated string and I'm calling it like this:

```
myBatch.bat ".git,*.tmp,file.c"
```

Inside the batch file I need to write a code that parses the argument that is passed at the command line and break it like this:

```
@echo off
set excludes=%~1
set excludes_cmd=""

FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%a IN ("%excludes%") DO (
   set "excludes_cmd=%%excludes_cmd%% --exclude %%~a"
)
```

So at the end, when I pring the 'excludes_cmd' variable I will get this:

```
--exclude .git --exclude *.tmp --exclude file.c
```

Comment: If you are going to use a `FOR /F` then you need to know how many tokens you will have passed to the script. In your case it is three, so you would be using `tokens=1-3` and `%%a` , `%%b` and `%%c`.  But you would be better off using a normal `FOR` command. `FOR %%a in (%~1) DO (call set "excludes_cmd=%%excludes_cmd%% --exclude %%~a"`

Comment: @Squashman, a standard `for` loop will resolve wildcards like `*` and `?`, but I believe this is not what the OP wants...

Comment: This seems not to be an easy task in pure batch scripting: `for` resolves wildcards (`*`, `?`), `for /F` needs a predefined number of items (`tokens`), sub-string replacement does not care about quotation (I guess there could also occur quoted strings like `'.txt'` in the argument, which could even contain `,` on their own, like `'x,y'`; right? such commas need to be preserved then)...

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with basic variable expansion and substitution:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "excludes=%~1"
If Not Defined excludes GoTo :EOF
Set "excludes_cmd=--exclude %excludes:,= --exclude %"
```

The variable, `%excludes_cmd%`, should contain your required content.

Answer (score 2):

Came up with a similar way as Compo, just inserting your examples as defaults.

```bat
@echo off
if "%~1"=="" "%~f0" ".git,*.tmp,file.c"
set "excludes=,%~1"
set "excludes_cmd=%excludes:,= --exclude %"
set excludes
```

```bat
excludes=,.git,*.tmp,file.c
excludes_cmd= --exclude .git --exclude *.tmp --exclude file.c
```